# How to save xpath query data to saveHTML with HTML tags?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I'm trying to understand how I can save the html string found by query so that I can access it's elements.

I'm using the following query to find the below ul list.

```
$data = $xpath->query('//h2[contains(.,"Hurricane Data")]/following-sibling::ul/li');

<h2>Hurricane Data</h2>
<ul>
    <li><strong>12 items</strong> found, see <a href="/link">here</a>for more information</li>
    <li><strong>19 items</strong> found, see <a href="/link">here</a>for more information</li>
    <li><strong>13 items</strong> found, see <a href="/link">here</a>for more information</li>
</ul>
```

If I `print_r($data)`, I get the following `DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 3 )` which refers to the 3 elements found.

If I `foreach()` into the `$data` I get a DOMElement Object with all 3 li data.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to put each li data into an accessible array, but I want to parse the html **strong** & **a** tags inside too.

Now, I've already did everything I want to do, except the strong and a tags aren't being inserted into the arrays, here is what I've come up with.

```
$string = [];
$query = $xpath->query('//h2[contains(.,"Hurricane Data")]/following-sibling::ul/li');
foreach($query as $values){
    $try = new \DOMDocument;
    $try->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($values->textContent, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));

    $string[] = $try->saveHTML();
}

echo $string[0];
// outputs = 12 items found, see here for more information
// no strong tags, no hyperlinks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to reprocess the data, you can just say to save this particular node...

```
foreach($query as $values){    
    $string[] = $doc->saveHTML($values);
}
```

Where `$doc` is the document used as the basis for your XPath query.

Comment: I feel so lame Nigel. Thank you.